# Deleting relationship in laravel without deleting the entry itself

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a User model with this relationship:

```
public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User','parent_id');
}
```

It is intended to hold users who you are following, to be able to see their posts in your feed.
When I follow someone, I do this (inside a controller):

```
public function follow($myId, $hisId){
        
            $me = User::find($myId);
            $him = User::find($hisId);

            $me->users()->save($him);
            $me->save();
}
```

Which is working. The problem is when I'm trying to unfollow, I end up deleting the user itself, while I
only want to delete my relationship with him. I'm doing this:

```
public function unfollow($myId,$hisId){
        $me = User::find($myId);
        $him = User::find($hisId);

        $me->users()->delete($him);
        $me->save();
}
```

Any help is highly appretiated.

Comment: Aren't you in the `User` instance when executing `follow` and `unfollow`? Delete does what it does, delete. Attach and detach does what is does, attaching or detaching.

Comment: No, when I click follow in someone's profile, I make an ajax call which endpoint URL goes into those functions, my and his Id are passed in the URL.

Comment: Yes, no .. yes .. you have an authenticated user right? Or is everyone able to unfollow anyone by just calling the request with random id's?

Comment: So first of all, to answer your question, usw `detach()` instead.

Comment: Yes, I have an authenticated user. The follow or unfollow button doesn't show up for guests. Thank you, I wlill try detach.

Comment: That doesn't matter if it shows up or not, I can call the request anyway and just change the id's to whoever I want, even if it is not my own ..

Comment: Yes you're right, I tried dettach and I get this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::detach()"

Comment: Yea, one-to-many uses `associate()` and `dissociate()` methods. Could you tell me the structure of the relationship table? You are using a many-to-many (pivot) table right?

Comment: I don't have a relationship table, should I? Isn't this enough? public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User','parent_id');
}

Comment: Um, if not, it would mean a user can **only** be followed once? No other user could follow this user too?

Answer (score 0):

- We add/remove the relation of a belongs-to (including has-many) with `associate()` and `dissociate()` as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships).
- We add/remove the relation of a belongs-to-many (many-to-many) with `attach()` and `detach()` as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

But I see a few problems in this approach.

This is obviously a many-to-many relationship, I don't see how a one-to-many is suppose to work here.

```
// @pivot table user_follows
------------------------
| user_id | follows_id |
|-----------------------
| 1       | 2          |
| 2       | 1          |
|----------------------|
```

I'll assume `follow` and `unfollow` are part of some controller and a similar route.

```php
Route::middleware(['auth'])->prefix('stalker')->group(function() {
    Route::post('follow/{id}/{follow_id}');
    Route::post('unfollow/{id}/{unfollow_id}');
});
```

```php
class StalkerController extends Controller {
  
   public function follow($id, $follow_id) {
      // get user by $id
      // get user to follow by $follow_id
   }

   public function unfollow($id, $unfollow_id) {
      // get user by $id
      // get user to unfollow by $unfollow_id
   }
}
```

Even if this controller is part of the middleware `auth`, everyone could just randomly call your route (if authenticated) and follow or unfollow users they don't belong to.

If I were to be authenticated with a user of id `1`, I could just call `/stalker/unfollow/2/1` (this would unfollow me if user with id `2` was following me) and/or any other id that isn't my user id.

If your route isn't throttled (for example with `['middleware' => 'throttle:3,10'])`, I could do a loop and be unfollowed by everyone (or the opposite, everybody is following me).

```php
// assume you don't have more users than 10.000.
$until = 10000;
// assuming this would be my user id.
$my_user_id = 1;
// I'll start with the next user.
$user_id = 2; 
// I just don't like to be followed.
while($user_id < $until) {
   // CURL is missing some tokens/session info, but pretend I added all that.
   CURL::call("yourdomain.com/stalker/unfollow/{$user_id}/{$my_user_id}");
   $user_id++;
}
```

So just get the authenticated user that **called** the route:

```
public function follow($id) {
   $me = Auth::user();
   // one to many
   $me->users()->associate($id)
   // many to many
   $me->users()->attach($id);
}
```

And your route only needs to contain the id of the user it wishes to follow or unfollow

```php
Route::post('follow/{id}');
Route::post('unfollow/{id}');
```